# Any man-in-the-middle (MITM) hashrate theft examples

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, attack, stratum

One benefit  of Stratum V1 to Stratum V2 is protection from man-in-the-middle (MITM) hashrate theft.

Are there any documented examples of man-in-the-middle (MITM) hashrate theft in practice ?

Like some paper, document, article ? I am not interested in theoretical, just practical documented examples. Understand it is not easy to detect, especially is only 1-2% hashrate is stole, but in 10+ years, if it is happening in practice, I would expect some documented examples.